# Listing files in specific depth

Tags: java, file

I must write a program that given a depth, it must list all the existing files and directories in that depth. So far, this is the code:

```
static String path = "path";
static int depth = X;
static ArrayList<String> filesindepth = new ArrayList<String>();

public static ArrayList<String> Filescanner(File files[], int depth)
{
    if (depth > 0) {
        for (File file : files) 
        {
            if (file.isDirectory()) 
            {
                Filescanner(file.listFiles(), depth - 1);

            }
            if (depth==1) filesindepth.add(file.getAbsolutePath()); 
        }
    }
    return filesindepth;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File[] file = new File(path).listFiles();
    Pfadscanner(file, depth);
    for (String files: filesindepth)
    {
        System.out.println(files);
    }
}
```

If I use depth 1, the code works fine, but when use a higher depth it just list  the files from the last found directory in the previous folder and I want the list of all directories and files in that depth(even if they are in different directories). Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Let's say I have a structure like the following:

- Root

  - Subdirectory1/

    - Subdirectory1.1/
    - Subdirectory1.2/
  - Subdirectory2/

    - Subdirectory2.1/

The programm should show me the absolute paths of Subdirectory1.1, Subdirectory1.2, and Subdirectory2,1.

**EDIT** Problem solved, thanks to @Ferrybig und @m.yadav. The final code is the shown above.

Answer (score 1):

### You are ignoring the recursive call

> ```
> filesindepth.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
> Filescanner(file.listFiles(), depth-1);
> ```

You are ignoring the call to the recursive `fileScanner`.

If making a recursive method, you should make sure the results from the other methods are correctly collected in a central place.

In your case, you can do this by calling [`Collection.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) as:

```
filesindepth.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
filesindepth.addAll(Filescanner(file.listFiles(), depth-1));
```

### Incorrectly scoped variable

> ```
> static ArrayList<String> filesindepth;
> ```

Why is this variable static? It should atleast be scoped to the `Filescanner` method, that way, you can build on it.

```
public static ArrayList<String> Filescanner(File files[], int depth)
{
    ArrayList<String> filesindepth = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (depth>0)
    {
        for (File file: files)
        {
            if(file.isDirectory())
            {
                filesindepth.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                filesindepth.addAll(Pfadscanner(file.listFiles(), depth-1));
            }
        }
    }
    return filesindepth;    
}
```

### You are ignoring the result of the call in the main method

> ```
>        Filescanner(file, depth);
>         for (String files : filesindepth) {
>             System.out.println(files);
>         }
> ```

You should get a list from the method, and then process the methods from that call, this is the OOP way of doing it.

```
        ArrayList<String> filesindepth = Filescanner(file, depth);
        for (String files : filesindepth) {
            System.out.println(files);
        }
```

Comment: I did the changes you recommended and according to the example the program is printing me the path of subdirectory 2.1 twice. The depth I gave was 2.

Comment: If I initialize the variable there the program doesn't show any results

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `filesindepth` list on every invocation of `Filescanner()`

which should be only once in your case. Updated running code

```
        static String path = "/tmp/aa";
        static int depth = 3;

        // initialize 'filesindepth' only once here..
        static ArrayList<String> filesindepth = new ArrayList<String>();

        public static ArrayList<String> Filescanner(File files[], int depth) {
            if (depth > 0) {

                for (File file : files) {
                    filesindepth.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        Filescanner(file.listFiles(), depth - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            return filesindepth;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            File[] file = new File(path).listFiles();
            Filescanner(file, depth);
            for (String files : filesindepth) {
                System.out.println(files);
            }
        }
```

For directory structure:

```
    tmp
        '--aa
            |-- bb
            '-- cc
                '-- dd
```

Output would be like:

/tmp/aa/bb

/tmp/aa/cc

/tmp/aa/cc/dd

Comment: Exactly, But if just want the path for DD, where should I update the arraylist?